# Compare two rows based on certain fields and flag them if differences found

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a table created in athena. The table structure looks like the following:

```
id (string)
event_val (string)
eventsource (string)
eventtype (string)
payload (struct<field1:struct<attribute2:struct<tokenRegion:string,tokenType:string,token:string>,attribute15:string,attribute1:string,attribute8:string,updatedAt:string,status:string,internalRevision:int,attribute13:string,attribute12:string,id:int,textLineCount:int,createdAt:string,attribute11:string,supplierNumber:struct<tokenRegion:string,tokenType:string,token:string>,shippingTermsCode:string,attribute10:string,attachmentTextConcat:string,attribute18:string,attribute4:string,fileName:string,textLineSplitCount:int,version:int>,textLines:array<struct<price:int,invoiced:int,attribute5:string,attribute11:string,status:string,id:int,lineVersion:int,suppAuxPartNum:string,total:double,attribute12:string,description:string,uOM:string,updatedAt:string,attribute2:string,texteld2:array<struct<segment2:string,accountAllocationSequence:int,segment3:string,segment4:string,orderLineId:int,segment5:string,attribute11:string,segment6:string,attribute12:string,accountAllocationId:int,segment7:string,segment1:string,fileName:string,accountAllocationAmount:double,version:int,orderHederId:int>>,quantity:double,lineNumber:int,sourcePartNum:string,lineType:string,version:int,fileName:string,needByDate:string,createdAt:string,orderHeaderId:int>>>)
```

In this table, there will be two entry for each event_val key. And the eventsource field will be either 'value_a' or 'value_b'. Basically, we are inserting two events of the same event_val value from two different eventsource.

I need to compare every such pair and find the difference if there is any. Some field in payload may or may not be there.

Also how do we make comparison on payload.textLines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map_agg` with group by on `event_val`

**Note: You need to check actual syntax. But something like following should do.**

```
With
intermediate_table as
(
  select event_val, map_agg(eventsource, payload) as payload_by_eventsource
  from <table_name>
  group by event_val
),
intermediate_table_2 as
(
select event_val, payload_by_eventsource['source_a'] as source_a_payload, payload_by_eventsource['source_b'] as source_b_payload
from intermediate_table
)

select .......
from intermediate_table_2
where....
```